# Problem with Gazebo's built-in PID controller

Tags: gazebo-1.0

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I using ROS fuerte version with Gazebo 1.0.2, my questions are:

1. When opening the Gazebo, there is some controller (PID) that is initialized automatically by default?
2. When creating a prismatic joint or the revolution Gazebo, is automatically added a controller (PID) in the joint?
3. Why the gains are limited at most 99,990 in "Control Joints"?
4. How to calculate the action applied to the joint using this controller's internal Gazebo?
5. In "Control Joints", the force, position and velocity are applied separately or is a summation?
6. There is documentation on this internal controller to the Gazebo?
7. What happens to the internal controller Gazebo when added a new controller?

My code URDF: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6300846 and Image "Joint Control": http://postimg.org/image/a0dvyrsl7/

Thanks, best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4213/problem-with-gazebo%27s-built-in-pid-controller./) by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-08-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-08-22**:
You should upgrade to gazebo 1.9. Version 1.0.2 is very old.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-08-22**:
I'll update my version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. A PID position or velocity controller is built into Gazebo for every joint. These controllers will do nothing until you send them a command.
2. See above.
3. The gain limit you refer to is just a GUI limit. You can send a message to Gazebo with any gain.
4. Look [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/b2d2cf062c2b09177badd4a63a1aa5a4e6791485/gazebo/physics/JointController.cc?at=default#cl-88) for position control, and [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/b2d2cf062c2b09177badd4a63a1aa5a4e6791485/gazebo/physics/JointController.cc?at=default#cl-103) for velocity control.
5. Only one force is applied to a joint in the following order of precedence: Force, Position PID, Velocity PID.
6. Search the [wiki](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/pid_control_joint), and look in the [API](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.9.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointController.html)
7. If you add another controller (say from ROS), then they two will conflict. You should really only use only controller at a time.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-08-22**:
Thanks for respond, is there any way to turn off this internal controller of the Gazebo or should I create a code to zero the parameters? Because I would like to create my controller.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-08-23**:
The controller is off by default.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-08-26**:
Thanks Nate, but I need your help, I have how set all parameters (PID) in "0.000" for this controller? I would like to start the gazebo with all parameters in "0.000". How can I do this?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-08-26**:
I'm don't think I understand the problem. By default Gazebo does not run a PID controller on a joint. You have to explicitly tell Gazebo to use it's internal PID controller. Do not pass any PID parameters to Gazebo, and you will be all set.